# How to prevent a Shiny Server dropdown menu from being cutoff

Tags: r, shiny

I have the beginnings of a simple Shiny App:

```
shinyUI(
  navbarPage("Round Robin",
    tabPanel("Setup",
      fluidPage(
        column(4,
           selectInput("quarter",label="Select Quarter:",choices = yyyyQQ[order(yyyyQQ,decreasing=T)],selected=1)
          ,textInput("pwd", label = "Enter Password:",value="")
          )
        )
      )         
    )
  )
```

For now, the `server.R` file is essentially empty (I started the project from inside R Studio as a new Shiny App - it's just what was initially created there) and I have a `global.R` file which loads `library(shiny)`, reads a csv file as a data.frame and creates the variable `yyyyQQ = unique(with(data,paste(Year,paste0("Q",Quarter),sep="-")))`.  There are 37 values in `yyyyQQ`.

When I launch the app the dropdown menu only shows 2.5 rows and creates a scrollbar for a small row of the whole page.

How do I prevent this behavior and allow the whole dropdown menu to spawn?

UPDATE: including the `dput` of `yyyyQQ` (and yes, I know that the variable name doesn't reflect the actual structure of the variable)   Also - I've tested this in Chrome and IE with the same behavior in both places.

```
c("09Q1", "09Q2", "09Q4", "09Q3", "10Q1", "10Q2", "10Q3", "10Q4", 
"11Q1", "11Q2", "11Q3", "12Q1", "11Q4", "12Q3", "12Q2", "12Q4", 
"13Q1", "13Q2", "13Q3", "13Q4", "14Q2", "14Q3", "14Q1", "14Q4", 
"07Q4", "06Q1", "06Q2", "06Q4", "06Q3", "07Q1", "07Q2", "07Q3", 
"08Q1", "05Q1", "05Q3", "05Q4", "05Q2")
```